# creating an authentication console application using GetTickCount function

Tags: c#

I'm trying to make a simple login/authentication console application, for example I have a string testpwd as my password and I want to the program to count the time in milliseconds the moment the user starts entering the password and it should output how many seconds each user takes to type the password every time I a user starts type from the keyboard with the help of the `GetTickCount` function.

I am not sure how I can go about it but the only thing I have managed to do is this code below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
namespace LoginSystem
{
    class LSystem
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello! This is simple login system!");
            Console.Write("Write your username here: ");
            string strUsername = Console.ReadLine();
            string strTUsername = "testuser";
            if (strUsername == strTUsername)
            {
                Console.Write("Write your password here: ");
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;
                string strPassword = Console.ReadLine();
                string strTPassword = "testpwd";
                if (strPassword == strTPassword)
                {
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
                    Console.WriteLine("You are logged in!");
                    Console.ReadLine();

                }
                else
                {
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
                    Console.WriteLine("Bad password for user: {0}", strUsername);
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Bad username!");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple [StopWatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx)? The relevant part of your code could be written in this way

```
...
Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;
StopWatch sw = new Stopwatch();
sw.Start();
string strPassword = Console.ReadLine();
sw.Stop()
TimeSpan ts = sw.Elapsed;
string strTPassword = "testpwd";
if (strPassword == strTPassword)
{
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
    Console.WriteLine("You are logged in after " + ts.Milliseconds.ToString() + " milliseconds");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
.....
```

Comment: Props for beating me to it with the same answer :-)

Comment: using System.Diagnostics, no need to reference new assemby. It is in System.Dll

Answer (score 0):

1- you can use DateTime.Now then subtract them to get time span.

2- Invoke GetTickCount but you need to declare it first like this:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern uint GetTickCount();
```

Answer (score 0):

First, your question is difficult to understand.  If I read you correctly, you wish to start timing when the user begins typing and stop when the user presses enter? How about using the [`System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx)?

Right before calling Console.ReadLine(), initate a new Stopwatch(), then call the Start() method.

Immediately following Console.ReadLine(), stop the stopwatch:

```
        Console.Write("Write your username here: ");

        var stopwatch = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
        stopwatch.Start();

        string strUsername = Console.ReadLine();

        stopwatch.Stop();

        string strTUsername = "testuser";
```